# Deleting drop output of a deleted build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

Is there any mechanism available (preferably through the TFS API) to delete the drop output of a deleted build?

We have a number of deleted builds were the drop output still remains, as a result of the retention policy of the build definition in the past not being set to delete "All".

Querying the relevant builds and "redeleting" with `IBuildDetail.Delete()` or `IBuildServer.DeleteBuilds(builds)` has no effect (which one may expect), nor does `IBuildServer.DestroyBuilds(builds)`.

Is the only option to get the drop location from the `IBuildDetail` and use the standard `System.IO` file/directory classes to perform the directory delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be my guess.  At this point those folders are just regular old windows folders, since the build(s) they were linked to no longer exist.  So I would expect to use a regular old delete folder command if I wanted to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The "Community TFS Build Manager" extension provides this functionality. Just delete your build and it will remove the contents from the drop folder as well.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdb84b4-285e-4eeb-9fa9-dad9bfe2cd10

Comment: Sadly not at the moment. However, I have seen that the API provides this functionality. Can perhaps add this feature in the next release.

Comment: Hello, the to clear drops folder of deleted build is not added to the Mar 2014 release of Community TFS Build Manager.